# Login Destination behaving differently on two instances of Drupal

Tags: users

I'm seeing some inconsistent behaviour from the [Login Destination](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_destination) module on my "UAT" site as compared to my "Dev" site. Both sites (AFAIK) have the same module configuration:

- Neither of the global settings is enabled
- There is only one Rule, as follows:

  - **Redirect to Page** *foo-bar*
  - **Redirect upon Triggers** *Login, registration, one-time link*
  - **Redirect from listed pages** : *Only the listed pages* - `<front>`

The problem is with the one-time link sent out on account activation.

The one-time link references a URL of `user/reset/[snipped]`.
At this location there is a "Log in" button.

Clicking this button on my Dev site, users are redirected to `user/NNN/edit?pass-reset-token=[snipped]`, from where they can edit their account details.

**BUT** clicking this button on my UAT site, users don't redirect to the edit profile page, but are logged in and redirected to `/foo-bar`, which is useless, because they can never set their passwords.

The only difference I can see between the Dev and UAT sites is that the UAT site is HTTPS while my Dev site is HTTP. Is it possible that could be a cause of this issue? If not, how can I go about debugging this?

Best regards,

MB

**UPDATE**

Problem resolved - I'm just recording the outcome in case someone Googles this page in future.

It was of course nothing to do with HTTPS.

Someone had previously enabled the Trigger module on my UAT site, and there was a Trigger defined on user login to redirect to *foo-bar*. This was causing the one-time link to be redirected.

Due to the large number of modules on our UAT site, I didn't find this for a while. Disabling the Trigger module restored the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See UPDATE above in main question for the solution.

FYI the problem was diagnosed by attempting to step-by-step trace through the Login Destination module, and then discovering that at one point I found myself in the `trigger` module code. PHPStorm for the win every time!